# Get a list of ID based on status of matching rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have example data like this: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IKYmQqkx)

```sql
create table card(id int,ka text,status int,modifiedon date);
insert into card values
(1,'ka1',1,'2023-11-13'),
(2,'ka2',1,'2023-11-13'),
(3,'ka2',0,'2023-11-15'),
(4,'ka3',1,'2023-11-13'),
(5,'ka4',1,'2023-11-13');
```

I want to display `id` with status `1`. If there is a card with matching `ka` whose `status` is `0` then both should not appear.

Expected result:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: _"If there is a card whose status is '0' then it will not appear. How to query in postgresql?"_ - with a simple, run-of-the-mill WHERE clause ...? If you don't know at least that much yet - then you should be reading a book or tutorial that explains some of the absolute basics, at this point. We are not here to _teach_ those.

Comment: because there is the same 'ka' there and has the status '0'

Comment: @TirtaSalsabila If you add a DDL statement instead of a picture, it can be used by others to reproduce your case. There are tools like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IKYmQqkx) that let you even share an interactive, executable version of your example. These check some additional boxes but you still need to show what you've tried already and what the problem with your solution was - even if you think you tried very little and it went very wrong, it's important to see that you *did try*, what you already explored and have some starting point.

Comment: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yTO8TEJ8)   `SELECT ID
FROM card c1
WHERE status=1
and NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM CARD c2
WHERE c2.ka = c1.ka
  and c2.status=0)`  using a not exists and correlation you can  eliminate those with matching ka and status 0

Comment: @xQbert Please vote to reopen and post a regular answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your spec translates directly into a [`not exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJv_mamm)

```
select id from card as current_card
where not exists (select from card where status=0 and ka=current_card.ka)
order by id;
```

If you want the highest `id` for each `ka` that only has status 1's, use an [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html#TUTORIAL-AGG):

```
select max(id) from card group by ka having bool_and(status::bool) order by id;
```

You can also find all `ka` that have a `status=0` and filter them out using a [`not in`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN):

```
select id from card current_card
where ka not in (select ka from card where 0=status)
order by 1;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJv_mamm)